# How to perform a Caesar Cipher with multiple shifts

Tags: python-3.x, caesar-cipher

For example, if I were to apply 4 shifts to "breakzone" than it would be intended to be like:

"b" would be shifted by 2 characters
"r" would be shifted by 3 characters
"e" would be shifted by 4 characters
"a" would be shifted by 5 characters
and then we'd start back at the initial shift amount at 2:
"k" would be shifted by 2 characters
etc...

here's what I have so far:

```
statement = input("Enter string: ")
multiple_shifts = input(int("Enter shift amounts: "))
def caesar(word,multiple_shifts):
    for ch in statement:
        if ch = statement[0]:
```

I know it's not much but I'm definitely lost and any help is appreciated. Not asking you to "write my own code" just point me in the right direction so I'd greatly appreciate any knowledge of this subject.

Comment: "cipher in which the letters of the alphabet are substituted by a different letter that have a fixed distance to the original letter." if each letter shifts by a different amount wouldn't be a caesar cipher?

Comment: Yeah I'm just not sure how I'd go assigning these shifts to the letters

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very crude implementation:

```
import sys

def caesar(word, shifts):
    word_list = list(word.lower())
    result = []
    s = 0
    for c in word_list:
        next_ord = ord(c) + s + 2
        if next_ord > 122:
            next_ord = 97

        result.append(chr(next_ord))
        s = (s + 1) % shifts
    return "".join(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(caesar("breakzone", 4))
```

If you wonder what's with `122` and `97`, those are the Unicode values for lower case `z` and `a`. You could easily change the above to support full Unicode (e.g. be able to encode `H3ll0` for example). [Here](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html#x0000)'s a Unicode chart that might help you.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it and sorry I couldn't upvote I have less than 15 reputation right now

Comment: Do I need to make the shifts part a list?

Comment: No, shifts is just a number, like, in your example 4.